# My machine learning model cannot classify data that it has never seen before

Tags: python, scikit-learn, machine-learning-model

I am creating a spam identifier to detect wheter an email is malicous. The issue I have is my model using the RandomForest Classifier showed it was 99% accurate.

csv: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mandygu/lingspam-dataset/code

However when I enter in an email which is obviously spam: like Subject: give me money now and credit card Email: Send me your credit card number.

The model would say that it is not spam.(same issue with Naive Bayes)

This is disheartning as I would hope it would classify things that were obviously spam;
however if i copy and paste answers from the csv file it would work.
Model:

```
X = df.sub_mssg
Y = df.label
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.12, random_state=0, stratify=Y)
tvec = TfidfVectorizer()

mnb = MultinomialNB()
model_5 = Pipeline([('vectorizer', tvec), ('classifier', mnb)])
model_5.fit(X_train, Y_train)

y_pred = model_5.predict(X_test)

print(confusion_matrix(Y_test, y_pred))
print("Accuracy:", accuracy_score(Y_test, y_pred))
print("Precision:", precision_score(Y_test, y_pred, average='weighted'))
print("Recall:", recall_score(Y_test, y_pred, average='weighted'))
```

---

code for saving model:

```
import joblib
joblib.dump(model_5, 'spam_model.joblib')
```

Moreover the way i am making my test case is that I am adding the prompt data into a csv the same way I trained it and same way I cleanesd it,
code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import joblib
import numpy as np
import re
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

# Function to decontract contractions
def decontract(phrase):
    contractions = {
        "won't": "will not",
        "can't": "can not",
        "n't": " not",
        "'re": " are",
        "'s": " is",
        "'d": " would",
        "'ll": " will",
        "'t": " not",
        "'ve": " have",
        "'m": " am"
    }

    # Replace contractions with their expanded forms
    for contraction, expansion in contractions.items():
        phrase = re.sub(contraction, expansion, phrase)

    return phrase

# Download NLTK resources
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('stopwords')

subject = input('Please enter the subject of the message: ')
message = input('Please enter the contents of the message: ')

# Writing to CSV with label
with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    field = ["subject", "message", "label"]
    writer.writerow(field)
    writer.writerow([subject, message, 'your_label'])  # Add a label here

# Reading CSV
oldf = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
oldf['message'] = oldf['message'].str.lower()
oldf.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
oldf.isnull().sum()

# Preprocessing
df = oldf.dropna()
df['message'] = df['message'].str.lower()
df['sub_mssg'] = df['subject'] + df['message']

# Decontract, remove stopwords, and lemmatize
stopwords_set = set(stopwords.words('english'))
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

df['sub_mssg'] = df['sub_mssg'].apply(decontract)
df['sub_mssg'] = df['sub_mssg'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in stopwords_set]))
df['sub_mssg'] = df['sub_mssg'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in x.split()]))

# Remove non-ASCII characters, consecutive duplicates, and repeated characters
df['sub_mssg'] = df['sub_mssg'].apply(lambda x: ''.join([char if ord(char) < 128 else ' ' for char in x]))
df['sub_mssg'] = df['sub_mssg'].str.replace(r'(\w)\1+', r'\1')
df['sub_mssg'] = df['sub_mssg'].str.replace(r'(.)\1+', r'\1')

# Tokenization and removing short words
df['sub_mssg'] = df['sub_mssg'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(word_tokenize(x)))
df['sub_mssg'] = df['sub_mssg'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if len(word) > 2]))

# Remove hyphens
df['sub_mssg'] = df['sub_mssg'].str.replace(r'-', ' ')

X_test = df['sub_mssg']

# Load the trained model
loaded_model = joblib.load('spam_model.joblib')

# Make predictions using the loaded model
Y_pred = loaded_model.predict(X_test)

# Display the predictions
if Y_pred == 0:
    print("this is not spam")
if Y_pred == 1:
    print("this is spam")
```